# Colour change of confidence bands

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the colour of the confidence bands of two data sets in a common scatter plot. The colour of the data set have been already changed from the default to costumized. Now, the colours of the confidence bands shall be changed to blue and green as well.

The data set looks like this.

I would appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Stage   OAL   TL
Blasto  57    95
Blasto  61    85
...
Oozoid  7     9
Oozoid  22   29
...

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("tidyverse")

p<-ggplot(ThomTOAL,aes(x=TL,y=OAL,colour=Stage))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.4,size=2.5)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)+
  labs(x="\nTL (mm)",y="OAL (mm)\n")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','green'))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.18,0.87),
        legend.text=element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        legend.title=element_blank())
p
```

Comment: Confidence band color is achieved by `fill`, so you'll likely want to add that as an aesthetic.

Comment: You are right that with `fill` I can add a colour to the confidence bands, but how do I modify them according to my chosen colours?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual()`. :)

Comment: I added `scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","green"))+`after the `scale_color_manual` command, but it still didn't change the colour?

Comment: Help us help you be adding a reproducible example. There's some good info on adding an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Using `scale_fill_manual(values = ...)` in addition to `scale_color_manual(values = ...)` after mapping a variable to both `fill` and `color` is the general way to control fill and color colors, so I'm guessing something else is going on with your code or dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for `color =` and `fill =` inside the `geom_smooth()` argument/method.

I used `mtcars` dataset for reproducibility.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, qsec, group = am, color = am)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              color = "blue", 
              fill = "green")
```

[image]

You can find [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) more information about it.